# How to implement weighted SVD on vowpal wabbit?

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, svd, collaborative-filtering, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to implement a One Class Collaborative Filtering (OCCF) Algorithm which uses weighted SVD.

I was using Vowpal Wabbit to implement regularized Matrix Factorization to get recommendations in case of multi-class ratings but I can't figure out how to extend Vowpal Wabbit Matrix Factorization to do weighted SVD.

How to implement weighted SVD on vowpal wabbit or which other software have existing implementations of weighted SVD?

Comment: What do you mean by "weighted SVD"?

Comment: By weighted SVD I refer to a technique of weighted low rank approximation of ratings described in this paper : http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2008/HPL-2008-133.pdf. Here they are using a technique of weighted Alternating Least Squares (wALS) to decompose a matrix instead of the simple squared loss function.